# Dropdown list from array

Tags: php

I have 3 tables:

```
//COMPANIES
company_id    company_name
1             APPLES
2             BANANAS
3             ORANGES
4             PEARS


// FOLDERS
folder_id    company_id    folder_name
1            1             GREEN
2            4             YELLOW


// USERS
user_id    user_group_id    user_name    user_company_access
1          1                MARK        1,2,4
2          1                PAUL        2,3
2          1                JAMES       4
```

I'm trying to create a dropdown which show only users which contain company_id in user_company_access (serialized)

Example, when select folder_id='2' dropdown must be show MARK and PAUL

```
// FOLDER COMPANY
$folder_id = '4';

// EXAMPLE COMPANIES
$result = mysql_query (" SELECT * FROM users");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);
$user_company_access = $row['user_company_access']; 
$bar = unserialize(base64_decode($user_company_access));


// DROPDOWN
<?php
    $query = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM users WHERE (folder_company_id IN (".implode(',',$bar).") ");
    
    if(mysql_error()){
        print(mysql_error());
    }
    
    echo'<select id="dropdown1" name="user_id" data-placeholder="[Select User]" class="select" style="width:100%;">';
    
    echo'<option value=""></option>'; {
    
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
                            
        echo'<option value="'.$row['user_id'].'">'.$row['user_name'].' </option>';
    
    }
    echo'</select>';
    ?>
```

Comment: What is the bracket after this `echo'<option value=""></option>'; ` ?

Comment: Your first query isn't using `folder_id = 2` that the user selected.

Comment: There's no `folder_company_id` column in the `users` table.

Comment: folder_company_id is into FOLDER table

Comment: But your query is `SELECT * FROM users WHERE folder_company_id IN ...`

Comment: `mysql_` functions are obsolete since PHP 5.3 (about). Use mysqli or PDO. It seems what you are trying to do is to join two tables. There're a lot of tutorial on the web about how to do it.

Comment: The `FOLDER` table has columns `folder_id` and `company_id`, but not `folder_comany_id`.

Comment: Why should `folder_id = 2` return `MARK` and `PAUL`? That folder ID has `company_id = 4`, and `MARK` and `JAMES` have `4` in `user_company_access`.

Comment: You shouldn't serialize and encode `user_company_access`. That makes it impossible to match that column directly in queries.

Comment: Actually, it's bad design to have a list in a column. You should use a many-to-many relationship table.